# Combining Regio-Ticket Bayern with "Grossraum" tickets?

Tags: trains, public-transport, germany, bavaria

If you stay in Middle-Franconia (Nuremberg and surrounding) for more than a week and want to travel withing that region with public transport, probably the cheapest option is the VGN-Gesamtraum 9-Uhr 31-Tage Ticket. It's valid for a month, and you can use it in work days from 9 hour, and in free days without limitation.

However, when you already have that ticket, and you want to travel with train somewhere outer "Gesamtraum" or "Grossraum", for example to Regensburg, can you combine that with [**Region-Ticket Bayern**](http://www.bahn.de/regional/view/regionen/bayern/freizeit/regioticket_bayern.shtml)? It seems to be the cheapest option, because it allows 50km back and 50km forth travel, and costs 11,50 Euro, 2 times less that Bayern-Ticket.

However, I have found no information if it's possible to combine them with "Grossraum" tickets. For example, if I take the train from **Nuremberg** to **Regensburg**, the route until Parsberg is covered by the "Grossraum" ticket I already have, and the route from Parsberg to Regensburg could be covered by Region-Ticket Bayern. The only problem is, it's the same train and I don't have a ticket for the full route.

I've failed to find any information about that in internet...

Comment: If the train stops in Parsberg, it would seem difficult to forbid or, if it is, to enforce effectively. If the train does not stop there, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this does NOT work. the validity of the Region Ticket Bayern clearly states that it's for trips that start or end outside of a Verkehrsverbund (VV) (not sure how to translate this):

> nur für Fahrten, die außerhalb eines Verkehrsverbundes beginnen oder enden

To see this info, [open this link](https://www.bahn.de/regional/view/regionen/bayern/freizeit/regioticket_bayern.shtml) and click on "Das Regio-Ticket Bayern gilt"

VGN tickets are for the "[Verkehrsverbund Großraum Nürnberg](http://www.vgn.de/netz/)", so you can only use the Bavarian ticket from it's central area to get to places that are not in a Verbund and back. Not from one Verbund to the other. Also, the Regio Ticket Bayern does not cover the RVV trains in Regensburg.

[This map](https://www.bahn.de/regional/view/mdb/pv/dbregio/ausfluege/bayern/bayern_ticket/bayern_ticket_2011/MDB90899-bayern_verbuende_2010.pdf) will show you where the VV's start and end.
On top of this, the [ticket online shop](http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/d) will automatically show you the Region Tickets for purchase if the trip you plan allows you to book such a ticket.

Comment: So the problem here is, that my trip will start in one Verbund (VGN) and will end in the other (RW)? Travelling from, for example, Augsburg to Ingolstadt would not be a problem?

Comment: It's not that easy. The Regio-Ticket covers only trains of the DB and some additional ones, see the list on the link. If you have have a DB train going there, fine. If you have to ride an AVV train to start in Augsburg, then not. Bayerischen Regiobahn GmbH (Augsburg-Oberhausen –Weilheim –Schongau) und (;Augsburg-Hochzoll –Ingolstadt - Eichstätt Stadt) is included for example. You have to make sure you are in the right train.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. I thought that Regio Ticket is for travelling by train between any cities in Bavaria with distance less that 50 km. But from your answer, it's not the case, when both of them are withing Verkehrsverbundes (even if within different one). So can I use them when either the target or the start is outside VV? Or only if both target and start are outside VV?

Comment: I first thought about that too and even drafted an answer but the way I understand the sentence, it's about forbidding travels *entirely* in one *Verkehrsverbund* (which makes sense).

Comment: The ticket is issued by the DB. Not all trains in Bavaria belong to the DB. The ticket in question explicitly lists which trains it's valid for. On top of that, the start or end has to be outside of any VV. You need to read the "Das Regio-Ticket Bayern gilt" part of the ticket description.

Comment: You mean: "nur für Fahrten, die außerhalb eines Verkehrsverbundes beginnen oder enden"? Should I understand it "outside any VV" or "outside this/given VV"? The text being in German makes it not easier to understand :)

Comment: it means "outside any"